# Creating a canvas element and setting its width and height attributes using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, html

I was just trying to do the following in jQuery:

```
var newCanvas = $('<canvas/>',{'width':100,'height':200,'class':'radHuh'});
$(body).append(newCanvas);
```

This is working (kind of) and generates the following markup:

```
<canvas style="width:100px; height:200px;" class="radHuh"></canvas>
```

As most of you might know `canvas` elements don't really like CSS dimensions but expect a width and height attribute, so this object creation failed for me.

I do know I could just do:

```
var newCanvas = $('<canvas/>',{'class':'radHuh'}).attr({'width':100,'height':200});
```

instead, but I was just wondering nonetheless if there is any way of telling jQuery that `width` and `height` should be treated as attributes when creating the element via `$('element',{attributes})` and not as CSS?

Comment: To be clear, `<canvas>` elements "like" CSS width and height just fine; as with an HTML `<img>`, setting the display dimensions via CSS scales up/down a bitmap. The `<canvas>` height and width properties/attributes are like changing the size of an image in Photoshop, setting the actual number of pixels in the source image.

Comment: @Phrogz that's why I was writing "don't really like"... In any case I guess that 99% of canvas elements will need these attributes as they don't match the default ratio and so on.

Comment: @Phrogz , yes, ok but to be clear, you'll need a bit of simple math to scale it properly in plain css. Otherwise the `canvas` will act (as you said) like a normal `img` tag but it will **NOT scale proportionally** and most users (as they have) have problems in actually understanding - exactly this quasi/similarity.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

jQuery try to match each attribute name with a jQuery function name. Matched functions are called.

`width` and `height` are jQuery functions, so your original code is equivalent to this:

```
  var newCanvas = 
    $('<canvas/>',{'class':'radHuh'})
    .width(100)
    .height(100);
```

[width(value)](http://api.jquery.com/width/#width2) and [height(value)](http://api.jquery.com/height/#height2) functions set **CSS** width and height of an element.

---

Relevant jQuery source code line (https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/attributes.js#L308)

```
if ( pass && name in jQuery.attrFn ) {
```

`attrFn` object definition (https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/attributes.js#L288):

```
attrFn: {
    val: true,
    css: true,
    html: true,
    text: true,
    data: true,
    width: true,
    height: true,
    offset: true
},
```

Comment: While this answer does effectively set the styled height and width, the question is asking about the canvas height and width attributes.

`$('<canvas>').width(100).height(100)` actually sets the style of the canvas.

The more appropriate answer is from @thecodeparadox. Using `.prop({width: 100, height: 100})` adds the direct height and width we're looking for.

Answer (score 31):

```
var newCanvas = $('<canvas/>',{
                   'class':'radHuh',
                    id: 'myCanvas'                   
                }).prop({
                    width: 200,
                    height: 200
                });
$('#canvas').append(newCanvas);
```

**[Proof](http://jsfiddle.net/pjQKg/)**

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. `.prop` sets the width and height appropriately for canvas elements.

Answer (score 10):

You can use like this

```
$('<canvas/>',{'class':'radHuh','Width':100,'Height':200});
```

Change the case and try

Comment: That's interesting. Is this happening by design or is this taking advantage of some inconsistency?

Comment: i guess it is checking for known css attributes!

Comment: this behaviour could change in later version of jQuery so keep in mind linking to frozen version

Answer (score 8):

It seem like changing the case of any letter will prevent jQuery from converting the attribute to a style, so ranganadh probably stumbled on to some unintended flaw in jQuery where it checks the attribute against styles, but not case-insensitive.

This for instance seems to work aswell ??

```
var newCanvas = $('<canvas/>', {heiGht: 200, widtH: 100});
$('body').append(newCanvas);​​​
```

The native JS attributes are not converted to styles, and I'd probably go with the below solution to make sure it's "future proof" ( `setAttribute()` seems to work fine aswell ) :

```
var newCanvas = $('<canvas/>');
    newCanvas[0].height = 200;
    newCanvas[0].width = 100;

$('body').append(newCanvas);​​​
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that this worked the best:

```
$('<canvas height="50px" width="50px"/>')
```

You can also add `id`, `class`, or other attributes this way. Because it is not in the `style=""` attribute,  it does not count as CSS and mess up your shapes.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** This is slower, see comments below.

This will likely be faster than any workaround posted here:

```
var attributes = {width: 100, height: 100, class: "whatever"};
$('<canvas width="'+attributes.width+'" height="'+attributes.height+'" class="'+attributes.class+'""></canvas>').appendTo(document.body);
```

Slightly less fancier, but it's esentially the same with less function calls.

Comment: Actually it seems to be a lot slower that way: http://jsperf.com/element-creation-vs-string-injection

Comment: @m90 Hm, interesting, I wonder what's the reason behind that then, it doesn't seem to be very logic.

Comment: jQuery won't just insert the String into the DOM but parse and handle it in many different ways. If you pass a plain HTML tag to the `$()` it can skip a call to `$.buildFragment` which seems to be pretty expensive and do the attribute handling via `.attr()` itself. See: http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.7.2&fn=init for what's going on.

Comment: @m90 yeah, this is what I thought shortly after posting the comment, makes sense. Good to know either way.