# javascript canvas stretches my Image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, canvas, drawimage

```
    $.fn.imageCanvas = function() {

    if (!document.getElementById('bgCanvas')){
        $('body').append($('<canvas>',{id:'bgCanvas', width:'500px', height: '500px'}))
        var canvas = document.getElementById('bgCanvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    }
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,438,300);
        console.log(this.width);
        console.log(this.height);
    }
    img.src= 'http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/demos/assets/darth-vader.jpg';
}
```

In ctx.drawImage i wrote x,y,width,height. But canvas stretches this Image.
How can I image with original width/height

Comment: 1) `width` and `height` don't take a unit. They should just be `500`. 2) if you are also applying width/height via CSS, they can skew the canvas drawing. This should be avoided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to show the image without scaling, use the [three-argument variant](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images#drawImage) of `drawImage` with just x and y:

```
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
```

If you want to clip the bottom and right edge to your specified size, use the [nine-argument variant](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images#Slicing):

```
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0,362,240,0,0,362,240);
```

The first four numbers set the x/y and width/height of the clipping rectangle, and the next four numbers set the x/y and width/height of the clipped image-rectangle that is drawn to the canvas.

**EDIT:**

The problem is that the jQuery function treats the `width` and `height` properties in the options object in the second argument as **CSS properties**, *not* as DOM object properties. If you inspect the HTML you generate, you'll find:

```
<canvas id="bgCanvas" style="width: 500px; height: 500px;"></canvas>
```

instead of what you want, which should be:

```
<canvas id="bgCanvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10433046/creating-a-canvas-element-and-setting-its-width-and-height-attributes) for a discussion about the problem. As a solution, I would suggest using instead:

```
$('body').append($('<canvas>',{id:"bgCanvas"}).attr({'width':500,'height':500}))
```

Comment: I alredy do that but Canvas strerches image again... :(

Comment: Does the simple three-argument version also scale your image? It absolutely should not. If it does, you may have a CSS problem with your canvas. Make sure you are not applying styles that affect the CSS width or height of the canvas.

Comment: common.css is empty, in html i don't uses css

Comment: As it turns out, jQuery actually is setting CSS properties, contrary to what you'd expect. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10433046/creating-a-canvas-element-and-setting-its-width-and-height-attributes) for a discussion of the problem. I have edited my answer with a new solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this library I recently created which can load an image, resize it fixed width & height or precentage and convert from or to base64 or blob.

https://github.com/vnbenny/canvawork.js

Hope this helps you!