# Creating a canvas element using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

I am new to jQuery can anyone tell how to do this?

I am doing this in between html code

```
<script>
var Canvas_width=400;
var Canvas_height=300;
var CanvasElement =$("<canvas width='" + Canvas_width + "'height='" + Canvas_height + "'></canvas>");
var canvas=CanvasElement.get(0).getContext("2d");

CanvasElement.appendTo('body');
canvas.fillStyle = "#000000";
canvas.fill();
</script>
```

Comment: Please post your **code as text** - you are expecting people to re-type your code when answering.

Comment: In [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10433046/2401386) question there are several answers that can help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a canvas element and setting its width and height attributes using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10433046/creating-a-canvas-element-and-setting-its-width-and-height-attributes-using-jque)

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create a rectangle the same size as your canvas before filling it:

```
canvas.rect(0, 0, Canvas_width, Canvas_height);
```

**Demo**

```js
var Canvas_width = 400;
var Canvas_height = 300;
var CanvasElement = $("<canvas width='" + Canvas_width + "' height='" + Canvas_height + "'></canvas>");
var canvas = CanvasElement.get(0).getContext("2d");

CanvasElement.appendTo('body');
canvas.rect(0, 0, Canvas_width, Canvas_height); // <======= HERE
canvas.fillStyle = "#000000";
canvas.fill();
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what this line does::::  var CanvasElement = $("<canvas width='" + Canvas_width + "' height='" + Canvas_height + "'></canvas>");

Comment: @ManishKumar It's using jQuery to create a `<canvas></canvas>` HTML element (DOM element), of the width and height defined above.

Comment: @blex.Sir.I want to set border to my canvas using  canvas.style.border = "red 1px solid"; . It's not working here in my case on browser's console it is printing "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'border' of undefined at some line number".

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you should do it.
Don't add the canvas context, add the element itself

```js
var Canvas_width=400;
var Canvas_height=300;
var CanvasElement = $("<canvas width='" + Canvas_width + "'height='" + Canvas_height + "'></canvas>");
// Add the canvas element, not the context: CanvasElement[0].getContext('2d')
document.body.appendChild(CanvasElement[0]);

// Now create the canvas context, this is what you need to draw something
var canvasContext=CanvasElement[0].getContext("2d");
// call beginPath() before drawing on the canvas
canvasContext.beginPath();
// Select the rectangle inside your canvas in which you want to draw something
canvasContext.rect(0, 0, Canvas_width, Canvas_height);
canvasContext.fillStyle = "#000000";
canvasContext.fill();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```